# Estimation of the law $Z_{1000}/\sqrt{1000}$ with an histogram (+ asymptotic positions)

Tags: probability, statistics, applications

We consider a sequence $A_n$ of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$. At the step $n$, a particle is thrown at the origin and is moving until it goes out of $A_n$ by a point $X$. The particle is moving at the right with probability $1/2$, or at the left with probability $1/2$.

We begin with $A_1 = \{0\}$. We note $A_{n+1} = A_n \cup X$.

Example : $A_1 = \{0\}$. At the step $1$, the particle goes out of $A_1$ by the point $-1$ (left) or $1$ (right) ; if it comes out by the right, we note $A_2 = \{0,1\}$. At the step $2$, the particle goes out of $A_1$ by $-1$ (left) or $2$ (right), we adds the point to create $A_3$, etc.

We note $A_n = \{L_n, ..., R_n\}$. $L_n$ is the leftmost point, and $R_n$ is the rightmost point of $A_n$.

We note $Z_n = L_n + R_n$.

I have to simulate $A_n$, $L_n$, $R_n$, $Z_n$ and $p_n = \dfrac{n+2-Z_n}{2(n+2)}$ (when $n$ is big). It's done. I find that $L_n$ tends to $-n/2$, $R_n$ tends to $n/2$, $p_n$ tends to $1/2$ and $Z_n$ tends to $0$.

But then, I have to represent graphically (using a histogram) an estimate of the law $\dfrac{Z_{1000}}{\sqrt{1000}}$, and determine the asymptotic positions of $L_n$ and $R_n$. I really don't know how to estimate this law. Someone could help me for this point, just with little indications ? (sorry for my bad english) ?

Comment: Someone could help me ? :(

Comment: Right on it, please wait a few hours before I get a solution. Ithink I'm going to use $Z_n=n+2-p_n(2($n$+2))$

Comment: Which leads to \begin{align}Z_{1000}&=1000+2-p_{1000}(2(1000+2))\\
&=1002-2004p_{1000}\\
\end{align}. I don't know what to do from it yet.

Comment: What is step $1000$ for $p_{1000}$ ?

Comment: I have simulate $p_{1000}$ : the results are 0.5249501, 0.4880240, 0.5079840, 0.5089820, 0.5159681, etc... Overall, the results seem to tend to $1/2$! :)

Comment: Great ! So the law $\frac{Z_{1000}}{\sqrt 1000}$ tends to $0$, it is not that different from $Z_n$! *chouette !*

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! Thank you so much !! =D